# How to set Dom.disable_window_open_feature.location value using JavaScript in clients firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am jag. as per User requirement, I need to Hide address  bar in Pop up window(Security reasons). i used window.open("http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.htm", "mywindow", "location=0,menubar=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=100,height=100"); in my JavaScript Which is working fine. But, for mozilla we need to set  Dom.disable_window_open_feature.location value.

In Web application how can i set this in users firfox browser? Is there any way to set this using java script.  I want setDom.disable_window_open_feature.location  value using JavaScript before i use window.open. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Mozilla doesn't allow you to change that setting from a web page due to for security reasons.